# How to use TextField text in dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, nsdate

I'm using this code in xcode as part of a countdown-timer:

```
    destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1392375102];
```

I also have a textfield where a user can input the epoch timestamp that dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 needs.

I store the textfield with:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[textf7 setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringKey7"]];
[label7 setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringKey7"]];
}
```

and

```
-(IBAction)save7:(id)sender {
myString7 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:textf7.text];
[textf7 setText:myString7];
[label7 setText:myString7];
NSUserDefaults *stringDefault7 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[stringDefault7 setObject:myString7 forKey:@"
}
```

The question is:

How can I take the value the user imputs, and place it where "1392375102" now is in the first code seqment?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear. Assuming you wanted to convert the `textf7.text` from `NSString` to `NSTimeInterval` you could do something like this:

```
    destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[textf7.text doubleValue]];
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for beeing a noob...
But still not working. Build crashing when testing, and it makes the countdown messed up showing negative values...

Comment: Verify `textf7.text` for its contents with debugger. The problem probably lies elsewhere, but you pasted only one line of the code accountable for displaying the date.

Answer (score 0):

```
destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[myString7 intValue];
```